# Need some help on DB2 sql query to get the history data

Tags: sql, db2

I have a table in the data base which maintains the history/changes.  I need the data from the table  with the changes made only to one particular attribute.

For example, Lets say  for a particular server records  the state was "switched on" in day 1 and switched off on day 2 and on day 3 a different attribute was changed and again on day 4 the server state was back to on. Now I only  need the changes made with respect to the server state and I am not interested in any other changes made to the server record.
Can some please advise me if a recursive SQL or self join would help me to get the relevant results...

any suggestions would be more appreciated

Comment: Sample data and desired results really help to explain your intentions.

Comment: Name State environment timestamp
SRV1 on dev 22.06.2016 
SRV1 off dev 22.06.2016 
SRV1 on dev 22.06.2016 
SRV1 off dev 23.06.2016 
SRV1 off prod 13.07.2016 
SRV1 on prod 14.07.2016 
SRV1 off prod 01.01.9999 

I have given a sample table and I need  server and its state changes. 
But, when we look the sate has not changed on 13.07.2016  and it is the env that is changed.
I want the  server name, state and the timestamp on when a particular server record was 
changed and not any other changes

Answer (score 0):

A self-join seems appropriate.

Points of attention :

Join only rows that pertain to the same subject (duh), keeping state_1/date_1 and state_2/date_2, retain only those where the two states are different, retain only those such that date_2>date_1, and finally add a filter condition using WHERE NOT EXISTS(...) that there cannot be any intervening date_3 between date_1 and date_2 for the same subject.

Comment: Name State environment timestamp SRV1 on dev 22.06.2016 SRV1 off dev 22.06.2016 SRV1 on dev 22.06.2016 SRV1 off dev 23.06.2016 SRV1 off prod 13.07.2016 SRV1 on prod 14.07.2016 SRV1 off prod 01.01.9999 I have given a sample table and I need server and its state changes. But, when we look the sate has not changed on 13.07.2016 and it is the env that is changed. I want the server name, state and the timestamp on when a particular server record was changed and not any other changes -- Can some one please give some more ideas to arrive at the results. I have  given the same data as well here